# JsonException in android programing

Tags: android, json, http-post

While I was getting parameters with http post I am getting a `JsonException`.

Here is the code below:

```
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {

        ArrayList<String> nameSuccess = new ArrayList<String>();
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        GeneralConstans GC = new GeneralConstans();
        HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost(GC.PasswordUrl);
        HttpResponse response;
        String result = null;
        try {

            HttpContext ctx = new BasicHttpContext();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("otpPwd", EdtText
                    .getText().toString()));
            httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,
                    "UTF-8"));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpget, ctx);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            if (resEntity != null) {
                result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                JSONObject arr = new JSONObject(result);

                name = (arr.get("name")).toString();
                error = (arr.get("error")).toString();
                nameSuccess.add(0, name);
                nameSuccess.add(1, error);
            }
            return nameSuccess;


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

at `JSONObject arr = new JSONObject(result);` line that I am getting the exception.

I am new to Android programming.

loccat :
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626): Activity tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.PasswordConfirmationActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@414fa9e0 that was originally added here
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.PasswordConfirmationActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@414fa9e0 that was originally added here
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:549)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.PasswordConfirmationActivity$GetName.onPreExecute(PasswordConfirmationActivity.java:140)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.PasswordConfirmationActivity$1$1.run(PasswordConfirmationActivity.java:53)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4591)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.PasswordConfirmationActivity$1.onClick(PasswordConfirmationActivity.java:50)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4754)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-14 16:23:59.388: E/WindowManager(10626):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 16:24:00.788: W/System.err(10626): org.json.JSONException: Value (JSONObject.java:158)
08-14 16:24:00.788: W/System.err(10626):    at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:171)
08-14 16:24:00.788: W/System.err(10626):    at tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.PasswordConfirmationActivity$GetName.doInBackground(PasswordConfirmationActivity.java:102)
08-14 16:24:00.798: W/System.err(10626):    at tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.PasswordConfirmationActivity$GetName.doInBackground(PasswordConfirmationActivity.java:1)
08-14 16:24:00.798: W/System.err(10626):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-14 16:24:00.798: W/System.err(10626):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-14 16:24:00.798: W/System.err(10626):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-14 16:24:00.798: W/System.err(10626):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-14 16:24:00.798: W/System.err(10626):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-14 16:24:00.798: W/System.err(10626):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)

Comment: Could you print and post the result variable?

Comment: Paste the `LogCat`, **please**. How can we know the exact exception ?

Comment: Are you sure the URL returns JSON? Does it return a JSON Object or an Array?

Comment: it returns JSOnObject

Comment: Error 500--Internal Server Error gives me that error

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code to connect to your webserver using the HTTP Post method:

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("SERVER_URL");
    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("otpPwd", EdtText
                .getText().toString()));
    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        post.getParams().setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);
        HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);
        json = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
        if (!json.equals("") || !json.equals(null)) {
            JSONObject arr = new JSONObject(result);
            name = (arr.get("name")).toString();
            error = (arr.get("error")).toString();
            nameSuccess.add(0, name);
            nameSuccess.add(1, error);
        }
        return json;
    } catch (NoRouteToHostException er) {
        er.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```